# Transpose columns to rows in Scala

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

Need to transpose the dataframe and save it as external table using Scala.
Tried to do using pivot but no luck, need to transpose all the columns in a DF to rows and corresponding values as sample_value columns.
My DF

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
2 3 4 1
```

Need final output as:

```
col_name  sample_value1 sample_value2
A         1             2
B         2             3
C         3             4
D         4             1
```

Comment: What result do you want if column `D` has values `6,7,8,9`? What if one DF column consists of a single value? More examples are needed to understand what kind of transformation you're after.

Comment: why the `pyspark` tag??

Comment: @jwvh what ever may be the value, complete thing has to be transformed. Columns to rows & rows to columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Before I proceed to answer your question, I would like to stress on the fact that this is a very expensive solution and should be used only when you don't have an alternative**.

Given a `dataframe` as

```
+---+---+---+---+
|A  |B  |C  |D  |
+---+---+---+---+
|1  |2  |3  |4  |
|1  |2  |3  |4  |
|2  |3  |4  |1  |
|2  |3  |4  |1  |
+---+---+---+---+
```

You can do the following to get a `new` column for headernames for the final `dataframe` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val tempdf = df.distinct().withColumn("new", concat(lit("sample_value"), rank.over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy("A")))).cache()
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+---+-------------+
|A  |B  |C  |D  |new          |
+---+---+---+---+-------------+
|1  |2  |3  |4  |sample_value1|
|2  |3  |4  |1  |sample_value2|
+---+---+---+---+-------------+
```

Now final expensive part is to use `pivot`, `union`, `withColumn`, `groupBy` and `aggregations` to get the desired output

```
val firstCol = df.schema.fieldNames.head
val restOfCol = df.schema.fieldNames.tail
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.first
var finaldf = tempdf.groupBy().pivot("new").agg(first(firstCol)).withColumn("col_name", lit(firstCol))

for(column <- restOfCol) {
  finaldf = finaldf.union(tempdf.groupBy().pivot("new").agg(first(column)).withColumn("col_name", lit(column)))
}

finaldf.show(false)
```

`finaldf` should be

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+
|sample_value1|sample_value2|col_name|
+-------------+-------------+--------+
|1            |2            |A       |
|2            |3            |B       |
|3            |4            |C       |
|4            |1            |D       |
+-------------+-------------+--------+
```